# Inequality $||\theta_x||_{L^{\infty}}+||\mathcal{H}\theta_x||_{L^{\infty}}\leq C ||\theta||_{H^{2}}$

Tags: analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, harmonic-analysis

If $\mathcal{H}$ denotes Hilbert transform and $\theta\in H^{2}$ classical Sobolev space. How to prove that there is $C>0$ such that
$$||\theta_x||_{L^{\infty}}+||\mathcal{H}\theta_x||_{L^{\infty}}\leq C ||\theta||_{H^{2}}.$$

Comment: What does the x subscript mean?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro $\theta=\theta(x)$ and $\theta_x=\frac{d}{dx}\theta$.

Comment: It is probably an application of Cauchy-Schwarz. Write $\theta(x)=\int_{\mathbb R} \hat{\theta}(\xi)\exp(2\pi i x\xi)\, d\xi$ and try to estimate the various terms. Recall that $\|\theta\|_{H^2}^2=\int |(1+\xi^2)\hat\theta(\xi)|^2\, d\xi.$